# Highlight rows with unique values when compared to a different sheet

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have two sheets:

The first is the Master Sheet of responses to a survey.

The second will be an Update Sheet auto-generated from the new responses.
New responses can be either entirely new rows or edits/updates to previous entries.

I am trying to create a Conditional Formatting rule to auto-highlight any rows in the Update Sheet which do not match the corresponding rows in the Master sheet. 
(A row "does not match" when it shares the same Respondent ID number as the Master sheet row but contains different information in the following cells.) 
I'm also trying to make it ignore any empty cells.

I created named ranges: "Master" and "Update" on each sheet respectively.

Here's an image of what I'm trying to accomplish: 
[image: Highlight Demo]

*I'd like to accomplish this without scripts or using a helper column if possible.*

Any help from you genuine experts out there would be greatly appreciated!

And here's the [Demo Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jrgh2IqGzEVmRL_eK50M1EflSZuuxyKOIaNvNfVkJGU/edit?usp=sharing) for reference.

---

So far I have tried to use INDIRECT to accomplish the cross-sheet highlighting (below). However, that didn't work so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

```
CONDITIONAL FORMATTING:
- Apply to Range: A3:A200,F5:F200
- Custom Formula: =ISNA(match(A3,INDIRECT("Master!F5:AS"),0))
```

---

Update #2:

---

With help from @I'-'I I've been able to get closer with:

```
CONDITIONAL FORMATTING: 
Apply to range: A3:F200
Custom Formula: =and(isna(match($A3,INDIRECT("Master!F5:F"),0)),not(isblank($a3)))
```

[image: Highlight Demo v3]

However, while it now highlights the "New Data" rows, it ignores the "Updated Data" row which has the same Respondent ID but different data in the following cells.

Any suggestions on how to rectify this would be appreciated!

Comment: @I'-'I Thank you! That gets me closer. 
Since I'm looking for unique values instead of duplicates I modified your suggestion to make it: `=ISNA(match($A3,INDIRECT("Master!F5:F"),0))`
However, now it ignores the "Updated Data" row and highlights the empty cells instead of ignoring them. 
Do you have any suggestions on how to address those issues?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your suggestion. When I replace the custom formula I have with `=and(isna(),not(isblank($a3)))` none of the rows are highlighted. Is there something I'm not including?

Comment: @I'-'I Thank you again! That updated formula gets me closer again. The empty cells are no longer highlighting.  I am trying to get the rows to highlight if a Respondent updates their information. This would mean that the number in Column A would stay the same but the information later in that row would no longer match the Master sheet.

Comment: @pnuts Perhaps I am missing something. I am not sure how to be more clear in what I'm trying to do. _I want the Conditional Formatting rule to auto-highlight any rows in the Update Sheet which do not match the entries already in the Master Sheet._ The first image I posted shows what I'd like to accomplish. Beyond that are there any additional questions which you would like me to clarify?

Comment: @pnuts An entry does not match when a row in the Update sheet contains data in any of it's cells that do not match those in the Master sheet with the corresponding Respondent ID number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @I'-'I I now have the following solution, which works perfectly. :

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($A3)),OR(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP($A3,INDIRECT("MASTER!F5:J"),COLUMN($A$1:$E$1),0)<>$A3:$E3),1)))
```

@I'-'I provided this explanation:

- VLOOKUP to lookup ID(A3) in the master sheet and return the
  corresponding 5 columns(5 cells).
- VLOOKUP results are compared
  against current row's 5 columns(<>A3:E3).
- IFERROR to return TRUE if
  lookup fails(suggesting NewData).
- ISBLANK to ignore blank rows.
- AND/OR/NOT Self explanatory. Used to combine TRUE/FALSE in a specific
  way to achieve intended result.

---

The solution by @AdamL also works, but I don't know how to give credit to two answers at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional formatting custom formula applied to range A3:F200:

`=IF(LEN($A3),IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(INDIRECT("Master!F5:J"),"where F = "&$A3&" limit 1")<>$A3:$E3),1),)`

HTH
Adam